# Is it safe to use Domain in Node for exception handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently its in Stability level: 2 which is Unstable, Is it recommended to use it?
Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: Depends, but I doubt anyone would recommend "Unstable" as something to use on a production system.

Comment: Works, very very very well. Otherwise, tell me how you handle errors properly in a real project.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas Stability level 2 does (as you both probably know) not mean it's not working well, just that the API may very well change the next release. It's worked for me too, but I'd hesitate putting it into production in a system I wasn't willing to refactor tomorrow in case things change.

Comment: I don't see where's the problem. Once you install a node version in a production environment you don't change it never or if you are forced to upgrade, in that case you will review the node change log and see if the domains syntax has changed.